# Remove duplicates from a file on specified match

Tags: text-processing

I have below example text in a file from which I want to remove the duplicates. Ultimate goal is to remove all duplicate instances(one of them is web:webapi) from this file.

Note this is a 600+ MB file.

```
"nirmal" -> ["app:am","app:am","app:identity_gateway","app:identity_gateway","app:loginsvc","app:loginsvc","app:loginui","app:loginui","app:ticket","app:ticket","app:webapi","app:webapi","ds:config_store","ds:config_store","ds:cts_store","ds:cts_store","ds:user_store","ds:user_store","web:am","web:am","web:identity_gateway","web:identity_gateway","web:loginsvc","web:loginsvc","web:loginui","web:loginui","web:ticket","web:ticket","web:webapi","web:webapi"];
"mbl" -> ["app:phx","web:phx","app:vas","development:mobile","s2:detsvc","s2core:detsvc","txn:detsvc","web:detsvc","app:fidoproxy","app:landing","app:mobile","app:noknok","app:optchart","app:redis","app:sentinel","app:spring","cws:mesg","cws3:wsproxy","s2:billpay","s2:services","s2core:billpay","s2core:services","web:fidoproxy","web:spring","at:admin","at:eqsroll","at:oqsroll","batch:admin","cws:ctnt","cws:risk","cws:user","cws3:acctaggtr","cws3:content","cws3:risk","cws3:rtao","cws3:rtmm","ets:ord","fhs:eqs","fhs:oqs","s2:aarcomm","s2:acctcomm","s2:espsvc","s2:ibsvc","s2core:aarcomm","s2core:espsvc","s2core:ibsvc","txb:b2bsvc","txn:acct","txn:ibank2","txn:olsvc","txn:rtmm","txn:services","txn:wtools","web:aempros_mpublish","web:b2b","web:etsecxml","web:ibxml","web:olxml","web:prospect","web:tablet","web:ticket","web:wtxml","web:xmlacct","web:xmlrtmm","s2:asset","s2core:asset","app:phxcfgsvr","app:phxdshbrd","app:webapiagg","s2core:mblsvc","s2core:snapquotes","s2:mblsvc","s2:snapquotes","web:landing","web:mobile","web:phxcfgsvr","web:phxdshbrd","web:webapiagg","app:phxcfgsvr","app:phxdshbrd","app:webapiagg","s2core:mblsvc","s2core:snapquotes","s2:mblsvc","s2:snapquotes","web:landing","web:mobile","web:phxcfgsvr","web:phxdshbrd","web:webapiagg","app:phxcfgsvr","app:phxdshbrd","app:webapiagg","s2core:mblsvc","s2core:snapquotes","s2:mblsvc","s2:snapquotes","web:landing","web:mobile","web:phxcfgsvr","web:phxdshbrd","web:webapiagg","app:phxcfgsvr","app:phxdshbrd","app:webapiagg","s2core:mblsvc","s2core:snapquotes","s2:mblsvc","s2:snapquotes","web:landing","web:mobile","web:phxcfgsvr","web:phxdshbrd","web:webapiagg","app:phxcfgsvr","app:phxdshbrd","app:webapiagg","s2core:mblsvc","s2core:snapquotes","s2:mblsvc","s2:snapquotes","web:landing","web:mobile","web:phxcfgsvr","web:phxdshbrd","web:webapiagg","app:phxcfgsvr","app:phxdshbrd","app:webapiagg","s2core:mblsvc","s2core:snapquotes","s2:mblsvc","s2:snapquotes","web:landing","web:mobile","web:phxcfgsvr","web:phxdshbrd","web:webapiagg","app:phxcfgsvr","app:phxdshbrd","app:webapiagg","s2core:mblsvc","s2core:snapquotes","s2:mblsvc","s2:snapquotes","web:landing","web:mobile","web:phxcfgsvr","web:phxdshbrd","web:webapiagg","app:phxcfgsvr","app:phxdshbrd","app:webapiagg","s2core:mblsvc","s2core:snapquotes","s2:mblsvc","s2:snapquotes","web:landing","web:mobile","web:phxcfgsvr","web:phxdshbrd","web:webapiagg"];
```

How can we do this in Linux?

Complete file having same formatted text in each line. I am trying something like search for the first string of each file which is separated by "->" and then look for the duplicates in its values which are separated by comma. if we find any duplicate then it should remove them.

Comment: Is that in a file? Is it the only line in the file? Should duplicates be removed from all lines? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Where is this coming from? Where is it going to? What did you try?

Comment: yes, that is in a file and yes I have many lines like that for different matching patterns in this file.

Comment: this information needs to be in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new here so not completely aware of that. Anyways I made changes to my question as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include more lines from your file. How can we know what lines to change?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So, ***all*** lines in the file look like `"something" -> [ "other:things ... ]` and what you call duplicates are cases where `other:things` is repeated on the same line? Is the order of the elements important? Will duplicates always be one next to the other? Is it OK if the output changes the order from the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/\("[^",]*"\)\(.*\),\1/\1\2/;t1'
```

- `:1` marks a jump mark for a loop
- `"[^",]*"` is one field. Excluding the comma from the pattern avoids taking `","` as a field. By putting the field in `\(\)` we can backreference the same field as `\1`
- The `s` command removes the second occurence of the same field along with the comma
- If a replacement was made, the `t` command jumps to the jump mark at the beginning

Comment: Thankyou so much. It works like charm for me. Though it takes a little much of time but accuracy is paramount for me which it does.

Comment: It's easier and faster if all duplicates will be immediate next to each other like seen in the first line: `sed 's/\("[^"]*"\),\1/\1/g'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
$ perl -lne '/^(.*?->\s*\[)(.*)(\].*)/; $k{$_}++ for split(/,/,$2); 
             print "$1", join ",", keys(%k), "$3"' file
"nirmal" -> ["web:webapi","web:identity_gateway","ds:config_store","app:ticket","ds:user_store","web:loginsvc","ds:cts        _store","web:loginui","web:am","ds:cts_store","app:loginui","app:am","app:identity_gateway","app:webapi","web:ticket","app:loginsvc",];
"mbl" -> ["s2:acctcomm","cws:mesg","txn:olsvc","app:loginsvc","web:b2b","app:loginui","app:optchart","app:phxcfgsvr","cws3:risk","s2core:billpay","s2:detsvc","app:spring","app:phxdshbrd","ds:user_store","web:ticket","batch:admin","at:eqsroll","s2:asset","s2core:mblsvc","txn:acct","app:am","s2:espsvc","development:mobile","web:fidoproxy","app:webapi","txn:rtmm","s2:mblsvc","app:redis","cws:user","cws3:acctaggtr","ds:cts_store","txn:detsvc","web:mobile","app:webapiagg","txb:b2bsvc","fhs:oqs","cws3:wsproxy","web:landing","web:olxml","fhs:eqs","web:prospect","s2core:ibsvc","cws:risk","web:phx","s2:ibsvc","s2core:espsvc","txn:services","web:ibxml","web:tablet","at:admin","web:identity_gateway","web:spring","web:phxdshbrd","web:phxcfgsvr","s2core:snapquotes","app:sentinel","s2core:asset","ets:ord","cws3:rtmm","web:loginui","txn:wtools","web:loginsvc","s2:snapquotes","app:fidoproxy","web:etsecxml","s2:aarcomm","web:am","web:wtxml","app:noknok","ds:config_store","app:ticket","txn:ibank2","s2core:services","s2:billpay","web:detsvc","app:landing","cws3:content","web:aempros_mpublish","s2core:aarcomm","app:mobile","web:webapiagg","s2core:detsvc","web:webapi","cws3:rtao","app:identity_gateway","web:xmlrtmm","web:xmlacct","ds:cts        _store","s2:services","at:oqsroll","app:vas","app:phx","cws:ctnt",];
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -lne` : run the script given by `-e` on each line of the input file (`-n`). The `-l` removes trailing newlines from the input and also adds a newline to each call of `print`.
- `/^(.*?->\s*\[)(.*)(\].*)/` : match three sets of data on each input line. The first, `.*?->\s*\[`, is everything from the beginning of the file until the first `->`, then 0 or more whitespace characters and then a `\[`. Because the pattern is in parentheses, we can then refer to it as `$1`. Next, match everything until the last `]` (`.*)`). This will be `$2`. And finally, match the rest of the line (`\].*`), this will be `$3`.
- `$k{$_}++ for split(/,/,$2);` : this is a trick to remove duplicates. make `$2` (the duplicated data) into an array by splitting on `,`, and then make each element of that array a key in the hash `%k`. Since hash keys are always unique, this will deduplicate the data in `$2`.
- `print "$1", join ",", keys(%k), "$3"'` : now, we print the original `$1`, the start of the line, then the keys of the hash `%k` joined by a comma, and finally the rest of the line, `$3`. This will not keep the original input order, but will deduplicate the data.

Comment: `perl -lpe 'my %h;s/[[,]"(.*?)"/!$h{$1}++ ? $& : $,/eg'` is another way to dedup+maintain order tailored for this data file. The method is v simple and the advantage is it doesn't oscillate to the end of string for finding the dups. It travels along merrily l->r nd detects dups as it goes along.

Comment: Just verify whether your outputs are ok. Where from does the "app.am" come in the second line of the order preserved case? This has to do with @items nd hash %k not reset for next line.

Comment: @RakeshSharma what do you mean? The OP's example starts with `"nirmal" -> ["app:am","app:am",...`. I don't see how I could be adding anything not already in the file.

Comment: `mbl -> ["app.am",....`  this is what i was referring to.

Comment: @RakeshSharma oh crap, you're absolutely right, I forgot to empty the hash! Thanks!